# Klout style pie chart

Tags: jquery, charts, pie-chart, klout, donut-chart

I am looking for Klout style pie/donut jquery based charts, the new ones that display the leading score in the middle. Can anyone point me to such a chart which I might be able to use on a website that I am developing. www.klout.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://rendro.github.com/easy-pie-chart/. This is the closest pie chart to the Klout Style Pie chart...

Answer (score 0):

[Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) can create torus charts, and writing some custom code to overlay a div containing the top score should be fairly easy.